# Google Hangouts Meet API Documentation

Tags: java, api, chat, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I'm looking for original api documentation for Google Hangouts Meet. I noticed that one the bots **hangups** https://github.com/tdryer/hangups uses these urls:

```
https://clients6.google.com/chat/v1/#{endpoint}
https://clients6.google.com/chat/v1/conversations/sendchatmessage
https://clients6.google.com/chat/v1/conversations/removeuser
https://clients6.google.com/chat/v1/conversations/createconversation
```

But I can't find any references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the very repo you pointed to has an explanation of where they got it from:

> Unlike its predecessor Google Talk, Hangouts uses a proprietary, non-interoperable protocol. hangups is implemented by reverse-engineering this protocol, which allows it to support features like group messaging that aren't available in clients that connect via XMPP.

basically, the author of that library just reversed those REST api calls. Presumably by using the actual google hangouts, and then looking at what network calls it makes.

I do not believe that google has any documentation on this.