# Can we record hangouts meet calls using Python?

Tags: python, hangouts-api

Is there any possibility to record Hangouts calls using Python? I want to find any method that records hangouts call using Python. I was trying to find a method by referring to [Hangout Api’s documentation](https://python-hangout-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). But I was not able to get a proper solution by using it. As well as I have gone through the following GitHub questions.

1. [Making a Video call using Hangout API [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41627977/making-a-video-call-using-hangout-api)
2. [Google Hangouts Meet API Documentation [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45253763/google-hangouts-meet-api-documentation)

But even those questions did not help me to get a good answer to my problem.

If anyone has done a similar thing tho this please give me an answer to get this work done. It doesn't matter whether that thing have done by using an API or background call recording script.