# Is Google Meet Android SDK available?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, sdk

I want to integrate Google Meet into my application but i cannot find any help for mobile sdk, also integrating direct apis is bit complicated. P.S. i am developing application in Kotlin language.

Please help if anyone has the solution for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sdk is not available bui API is available for the same. you can check these links - https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/usage/customer/meet and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45253763/google-hangouts-meet-api-documentation

Answer (score 0):

Google Meet now has published [Google Meet Live Sharing SDK](https://developers.google.com/meet/live-sharing/guides/Android/get-started). You can integrate Google Meet in your Android app (only Java language is supported by now)